# Vuetify button icon with inline text

Tags: user-interface, material-design, vuetify.js

what I would like to achieve is a `v-chip` that act as a button and not like something to select...

So far I tried:

```
<v-btn icon>
  <v-avatar>
    <img :src="user.avatar" />
  </v-avatar>
  My Text
</v-btn>
```

But it is not looking as expected...

I also tried to wrap everything inside a chip but even here I can not manage to let it work properly...

Can someone explain how can I do it? Basically in my top toolbar I need to display the user icon with its name on the right, it should be inline with other `v-btn icon` elements and also, by clicking on the `chip/btn` it should open a dropdown...

Of course I don't need all this from you, just to understand how to create a icon button with some inline text on the right...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used `v-chip` to create a icon with text inline and used css to change the pointer of `v-chip`, wrapped with `v-hover` to maintain the elevation on  hover and lastly wrapped `v-hover` by `v-menu` to show dropdown menu list when v-chip is clicked.

```
<div id="app">
    <v-menu offset-y>
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-hover>
                <v-chip  slot-scope="{ hover }"
                         :class="`elevation-${hover ? 5 : 2}`"  v-ripple  color="indigo" text-color="white" v-on="on">
                    <v-avatar>
                        <v-icon>account_circle</v-icon>
                    </v-avatar>
                    Sagar
                </v-chip>
             </v-hover>
        </template>
       <v-list>
           <v-list-tile
               v-for="(item, i) in items"
               :key="i"
               @click=""
           >
               <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
           </v-list-tile>
        </v-list>
    </v-menu>
</div>

<script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data() {
        return {
          items: [
            { title: 'Click Me' },
            { title: 'Click Me' },
            { title: 'Click Me' },
            { title: 'Click Me 2' }
          ],
       }
     }
   })
</script>

<style>
    .v-chip .v-chip__content{
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: This is Awesome! Thanks for your help!!